# RelativeLayout for Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have been experimenting today with making an Android Application, but I have tried the LineairLayout to make a welcom screen for my application, but I cannot get it right..

So I tried RelativeLayout and I saw I can move my ImageViews and buttons to everywhere. So my question is if I will move the items to places like center, bottom left and bottom right. Would this be a problem or all phones since not all phones have the same dimensions?

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome_screen_relative);

        final ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
        int displayHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        int displayWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        float scaledDensity = metrics.scaledDensity;

        BitmapFactory.Options dimensions = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
        dimensions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.log, dimensions);
        int imageHeight = dimensions.outHeight;
        int imageWidth =  dimensions.outWidth;

        float percentageToMoveViewDown = (float) 20.0;
        float viewY_float = (float) ((displayHeight / 100.0) * percentageToMoveViewDown);
        int viewY_int = Math.round(viewY_float);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams view_Layout_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        view_Layout_params.topMargin = viewY_int;
        logo.setLayoutParams(view_Layout_params);
        logo.getLayoutParams().height = imageHeight;
        logo.getLayoutParams().width = imageWidth;

    }
```

Comment: No, the phones will move them to the correct places.  The only possible problem would be on very small phones they might overlap, depending on the views sizes.

Comment: @GabeSechan - how would I prevent that? Any code that could help me, or even an article?

Comment: This is whi you should provide different drawable folders related to the different resolutions containing images is different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Thats depends. If you give objects a fixed size of course it will. for `dp/dpi` make sure to test it in Emu or real devices. You can also create density and orientation specific layout to support many screens. Consider that there are not only changes in size but also aspect ration and resolution and DPI.

For most apps `RelativeLayout`  <strike>is</strike>  might be the right approach.

You can read an excelent article about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

If the items have fixed sizes you always will have trouble with some phones. For the big ones it may be too small, for the small ones too big...
In my experience Androids small/normal/large screens won't help you much for configuring, since the differences are just too big.
If you want to make sure everything sits where it belongs to, you could get the device metrics. That way you don't even need to rely on center, but you can work with percentages to place everything where you want it to be. Plus you can set the sizes in percentage, which is great. Like you could say I want a button thats width is 50% of the screen, no matter how large the screen is. Its more work (maybe even overkill), but I really like that approach. Once you figured it out its basically just a bit copy paste at the start of your classes.
Example:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
int displayHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
int displayWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
float scaledDensity = metrics.scaledDensity;

//move some View 20% down:
float percentageToMoveViewDown = (float) 20.0;
float viewY_float = (float) ((displayHeight / 100.0) * percentageToMoveViewDown);
int viewY_int = Math.round(viewY_float);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams view_Layout_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
view_Layout_params.topMargin = viewY_int;
view.setLayoutParams(view_Layout_params);

//even works with text size for a TextView:
float percentageToResizeTextViewTextSize = (float) 3.1;
float textViewTextSize_float = (float) ((displayHeight / 100.0) * percentageToResizeTextViewTextSize);
int textViewTextSize_int = Math.round(textViewTextSize_float / scaledDensity);
textView.setTextSize(textViewTextSize_int);
```

Just a side note for the overkill thing: This should be only necessary if you want to support small devices (they mostly run something like android 2.3, but still are sold as budget phones) and big devices as well, but the trouble with the big ones is not as big as the trouble with the small ones. I personally rather put more effort in it than less, you never know.

Edit: ImageView by code
The easiest way is to do it hybridly, using xml and code. Note that you will have to change width and height if you set it to 0 in xml like in the following example.
Just place it in the xml where you would anyways, somewhere in your RelativeLayout.

In your xml:

```
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/myImageView"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

In your Code:

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
```

You now can work with that myImageView as I did it with view and textView. You can even set the image right here in code.
This imageView with the size of 0,0 is now placed where it would have been before. Now you could set the width to like 50% of the screenwidth and the height to...lets say 40% of the screen height. Then You would need to place it. If you want to center it you know that there must be 25% of the screen on each side, so you can add 25% as left and right margin.

Edit 2: maintain original imagesize
If you want to keep the original size of a image in your drawables, you can get its width and height like this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options dimensions = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
dimensions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourImageName, dimensions);
int imageHeight = dimensions.outHeight;
int imageWidth =  dimensions.outWidth;
```

Now that you have that, you could use it to calculate the aspect ratio to keep it.
Now since you know the devices width and height, you can easily calculate how much of the screen this image will need.(imageheight/screenheight*100 = your percentage of the screen you want the imageviews height to be). So the Height you set to the imageview would be `displayHeight / 100 * (imageHeight / displayHeight * 100)`.
How to place that? 
Now if you take a Screenheight of 100 and a imageheight of 80 you get 80%. You would now take this percentage and divide it from 100. Divide that /2 and you know how much space you would have as top and bottom margins if you wanted it to be placed in the middle of the screen (you would have to do the same for width).
Caution: If you don't want it to be relative to the screensize but the original size, that percentage approach is kind of pointless. If you do to your image what I just described, it may still be too big for small devices and too small for big ones. Instead you could think about what percentage would look good in proportion to the rest of the stuff on the screen and resize it to that, since it would have that relative size on all devices.

Edit 3:
Since you load the image in original size, it will be small on big devices if it is a small image.

```
//first you need to know your aspect ratio. 
float ratio = imageWidth / imageHeight;

//lets say you wanted the image to be 50% of the screen:
float percentageToResizeImageTo = (float) 50.0;
float imageX_float = (float) ((displayHeight / 100.0) * percentageToResizeImageTo);
int imageX_int = Math.round(imageX_float);
//now you know how much 50% of the screen is

imageWidth = imageX_int;
imageHeight = imageWidth * ratio;

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams view_Layout_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(imageHeight, imageWidth);
view_Layout_params.topMargin = viewY_int;
logo.setLayoutParams(view_Layout_params);
logo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.Fit_XY);
```

Comment: Very nice idea @tritop. How would I put an ImageView on the layout using code?

Comment: Alright, so I tried it and it made the image a lot bigger. How would I keep it the same size? (but it will still move it to a specific location)

Comment: Edited again to show you that. Besides from the code to get to know the image dimensions its just a little math.

Comment: I see, tritop. Does ImageView have any method to set the width/height?

Comment: @user2527967
myImageView.getLayoutParams().height = heightYouWantToSet;
myImageView.getLayoutParams().width = widthYouWantToSet;

Comment: I just tried that and that made my background move.. I edited my first post.

Comment: @user2527967  
I did an edit 3, you could do it like this.  
I don't exactly get the background move thing. You have set a background image to what? To your RelativeLayout?

Comment: I fixed that issue. But as expected, the logo is super small on my HTC One now. Any math could fix that?

Comment: @user2527967  
I'm not too good at math neither, but this should work. I updated edit 3 again. Right now you are setting the imageWidth and height as the size of the ImageView. You dont have any resizing. But since you know how you want it to look, you could just use a percentage that you think would look good, just play a bit with the values. The nice thing about this is that it will look the same on all devices, being smaller for smaller ones and bigger for bigger ones.